# Visual Studio 2015 RTM Installer crashes with NullReferenceException in ManagedUx.dll

Tags: windows-10, crash, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 RTM Installer crashes with `NullReferenceException` in `ManagedUx.dll` under Windows 10.

Basically, the same issue as [this one](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1544988/uninstaller-crashes), marked "as fixed" on Microsoft Connect, but it's not fixed for me.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 5):

I wasted half of my day trying to find a workaround, and here's what helped, eventually. My Windows 10 instance had the .NET 3.5 optional component installed. Switching it off brought the Visual Studio 2015 Installer back to life:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what led you to try this, but it's the only thing that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Noseratio, you are a little bit of a hero.